# LC matching or pi filter used in rf

Tags: passive-networks, impedance-matching

I am working in RF and if i go through articles it is seen that in every point where the RF signal flows it is said we need  LC matching networks or Pi filters, but i cant get the sole reason why they are used.
If it was for impedance match only for matching 50 ohm , we can do it by a trace only ryt because we can get 50 ohm through  that trace only by adjusting the trace width,length etc?
Are those filters or matching networks used to for tuning  or harmonic imbalance,if it is how do we design that?

Comment: Your trace should already be 50 ohm (or whatever your characteristic impedance is). Your matching network is there to make sure the trace sees an impedance of 50 ohms at the input of say a transistor.

In addition, a matching network using an LC or Pi network might be smaller than something like a \$\lambda/4\$ matching network.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but since there are other issues like harmonic imbalance, noise etc,,, they also serve a filtering purpose ryt. so how do we design those filters for matching as well as for other tuning purposes?

Comment: Welcome to the world of design, where many different requirements must be (sub)optimally satisfied by the designer. Continue your learning, ask more questions, read and understand all the maths. If you are not willing to stay up late at night and eagerly discover the truths of science by working the maths until you can work the maths in your head in a noisy bar while half-drunk, then go to business school instead.